# Expose spring integration amqp/jms channel messages metrics to prometheus

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, prometheus, metrics

I am trying to enable metrics to feed message statistics from a spring-integration RabbitMq <=> MqSeries gateway into Prometheus.

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/metrics.html#micrometer-integration) states that the channel must extends AbstractMessageChannel in order the metrics to apply. Since I am quite uncomfortable with [namespaces](http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-5.2.xsd), I am not sure if this is the case here.
Also, I don't understand how to add a MeterRegistryBean (and which one!) in order to trigger the metrics on.
And eventually, I don't understand how to use it.
Basically, since I am new to most of the framework implied here, the documentation here lacks an example that could help me understand it a little better.

Here's how I do my channel definition (the "xml" way is not a choice : It is already implemented this way and I cannot change it ftm) :

```
    <!--    *** MQseries  ***       -->
    <!-- ========================== -->
    
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" >
          <property...>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory_cred"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
        <property...>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="connectionFactoryCaching" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
          <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory_cred" />
          <property...>
    </bean> 
    
    <bean id="jmsQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="jmsConnectionFactory">
          <property...>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="fixedBackOff" class="org.springframework.util.backoff.FixedBackOff">
          <property...>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean id="myListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" >
        <property...>
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryCaching" />
        <property name="destination" ref="jmsQueue" />
    </bean>
    
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" container="myListener" channel="channelMQ_RMQ" error-channel="processChannel1"/>

    <!--    *** Rabbit  ***     -->
    <!-- ====================== -->

    <bean id="connectionAmqpFactoryDest" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
          <property...>
    </bean>

    <!-- Attribute : addresses = List of addresses; e.g. host1,host2:4567,host3 - overrides host/port if supplied. -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" 
            connection-factory="connectionAmqpFactoryDest"
            addresses="..." ... />

    <bean id="simpleMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter">
          <property...>
    </bean>     
    <rabbit:template    id="rabbitTemplate" 
                        connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"  
                        mandatory="true" 
                        channel-transacted="true" 
                        message-converter="simpleMessageConverter"/>

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter  channel="channelMQ_RMQ" 
                                        ...
                                        amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" />
```

Any idea on how I can do that?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Integration metrics (as well as Spring JMS and Spring AMQP) are fully based on the Micrometer implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#micrometer-integration. That all is good if you use some of the latest, supported Spring Integration version: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn.

If you don't use Spring Boot, then you need to declare a `MeterRegistry` bean in the application context. And probably the one exactly for Prometheus: https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus.

If you are new to the framework, consider to move away from the XML configuration in favor of Java DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl.

Also make yourself familiar with Spring Boot which really auto-configurs for us many things, even a `MeterRegistry` for Prometheus: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Comment: My main problem is that all thoses lack exemples. Should I be experienced with all those frameworks, the docs here would be perfectly obvious. But I like the doc about prometheus part within micrometer; thanks